# Python3 creating venv hangs - MacOS Monterey

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos, python-venv

Up until this morning I was able to create virtual environment using the following command:

> python3 -m venv venv

No issues at all, it was fairly quick. Nothing has changed on the system since ( I believe ), but now this command hangs indefinitely.

Running **python3 -v -m venv venv** gives some verbose output and it seems to be hung, here is the output:

> import _frozen_importlib # frozen import _imp # builtin import
> '_thread' # <class '_frozen_importlib.BuiltinImporter'> import
> '_warnings' # <class '_frozen_importlib.BuiltinImporter'> import
> '_weakref' # <class '_frozen_importlib.BuiltinImporter'> import '_io'
> <class '_frozen_importlib.BuiltinImporter'> import 'marshal' # <class '_frozen_importlib.BuiltinImporter'> import 'posix' # <class
> '_frozen_importlib.BuiltinImporter'> import
> '_frozen_importlib_external' # <class
> '_frozen_importlib.FrozenImporter'>  installing zipimport hook import
> 'time' # <class '_frozen_importlib.BuiltinImporter'> import
> 'zipimport' # <class '_frozen_importlib.FrozenImporter'>  installed
> zipimport hook
> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/encodings/**pycache**/**init**.cpython-310.pyc
> matches
> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/encodings/**init**.py
> code object from
> '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/encodings/**pycache**/**init**.cpython-310.pyc'
> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/**pycache**/codecs.cpython-310.pyc
> matches
> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/codecs.py
> code object from
> '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/**pycache**/codecs.cpython-310.pyc'
> import '_codecs' # <class '_frozen_importlib.BuiltinImporter'> import
> 'codecs' # <_frozen_importlib_external.SourceFileLoader object at
> 0x104397220>
> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/encodings/**pycache**/aliases.cpython-310.pyc
> matches
> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/encodings/aliases.py
> code object from
> '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/encodings/**pycache**/aliases.cpython-310.pyc'
> import 'encodings.aliases' #
> <_frozen_importlib_external.SourceFileLoader object at 0x1043ec7f0>
> import 'encodings' # <_frozen_importlib_external.SourceFileLoader
> object at 0x1043970a0>
> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/encodings/**pycache**/utf_8.cpython-310.pyc
> matches
> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/encodings/utf_8.py
> code object from
> '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/encodings/**pycache**/utf_8.cpython-310.pyc'
> import 'encodings.utf_8' #
> <_frozen_importlib_external.SourceFileLoader object at 0x104396f80>
> import '_signal' # <class '_frozen_importlib.BuiltinImporter'>
> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/**pycache**/io.cpython-310.pyc
> matches
> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/io.py
> code object from
> '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/**pycache**/io.cpython-310.pyc'
> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/**pycache**/abc.cpython-310.pyc
> matches
> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/abc.py
> code object from
> '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/**pycache**/abc.cpython-310.pyc'
> import '_abc' # <class '_frozen_importlib.BuiltinImporter'> import
> 'abc' # <_frozen_importlib_external.SourceFileLoader object at
> 0x1043ecb20> import 'io' #
> <_frozen_importlib_external.SourceFileLoader object at 0x1043ec910>
> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/**pycache**/site.cpython-310.pyc
> matches
> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site.py
> code object from
> '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/**pycache**/site.cpython-310.pyc'
> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/**pycache**/os.cpython-310.pyc
> matches
> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/os.py
> code object from
> '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/**pycache**/os.cpython-310.pyc'
> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/**pycache**/stat.cpython-310.pyc
> matches
> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/stat.py
> code object from
> '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/**pycache**/stat.cpython-310.pyc'
> import '_stat' # <class '_frozen_importlib.BuiltinImporter'> import
> 'stat' # <_frozen_importlib_external.SourceFileLoader object at
> 0x1043eed40>
> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/**pycache**/_collections_abc.cpython-310.pyc
> matches
> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/_collections_abc.py
> code object from
> '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/**pycache**/_collections_abc.cpython-310.pyc'
> import '_collections_abc' #
> <_frozen_importlib_external.SourceFileLoader object at 0x1043ef0a0>
> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/**pycache**/posixpath.cpython-310.pyc
> matches
> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/posixpath.py
> code object from
> '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/**pycache**/posixpath.cpython-310.pyc'
> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/**pycache**/genericpath.cpython-310.pyc
> matches
> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/genericpath.py
> code object from
> '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/**pycache**/genericpath.cpython-310.pyc'
> import 'genericpath' # <_frozen_importlib_external.SourceFileLoader
> object at 0x1044258d0> import 'posixpath' #
> <_frozen_importlib_external.SourceFileLoader object at 0x1043ef130>
> import 'os' # <_frozen_importlib_external.SourceFileLoader object at
> 0x1043ed960>
> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/**pycache**/_sitebuiltins.cpython-310.pyc
> matches
> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/_sitebuiltins.py
> code object from
> '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/**pycache**/_sitebuiltins.cpython-310.pyc'
> import '_sitebuiltins' # <_frozen_importlib_external.SourceFileLoader
> object at 0x1043eea40> Processing user site-packages Processing global
> site-packages Adding directory:
> '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages'
> Processing .pth file:
> '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/distutils-precedence.pth'
> import 'site' # <_frozen_importlib_external.SourceFileLoader object at
> 0x1043ed330> Python 3.10.4 (v3.10.4:9d38120e33, Mar 23 2022, 17:29:05)
> [Clang 13.0.0 (clang-1300.0.29.30)] on darwin Type "help",
> "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/**pycache**/runpy.cpython-310.pyc
> matches
> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/runpy.py
> code object from
> '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/**pycache**/runpy.cpython-310.pyc'
> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/importlib/**pycache**/**init**.cpython-310.pyc
> matches
> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/importlib/**init**.py
> code object from
> '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/importlib/**pycache**/**init**.cpython-310.pyc'
> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/**pycache**/warnings.cpython-310.pyc
> matches
> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/warnings.py
> code object from
> '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/**pycache**/warnings.cpython-310.pyc'
> import 'warnings' # <_frozen_importlib_external.SourceFileLoader
> object at 0x104426290> import 'importlib' #
> <_frozen_importlib_external.SourceFileLoader object at 0x104426710>
> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/importlib/**pycache**/machinery.cpython-310.pyc
> matches
> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/importlib/machinery.py
> code object from
> '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/importlib/**pycache**/machinery.cpython-310.pyc'
> import 'importlib.machinery' #
> <_frozen_importlib_external.SourceFileLoader object at 0x104425c00>
> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/importlib/**pycache**/util.cpython-310.pyc
> matches
> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/importlib/util.py
> code object from
> '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/importlib/**pycache**/util.cpython-310.pyc'
> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/importlib/**pycache**/_abc.cpython-310.pyc
> matches
> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/importlib/_abc.py
> code object from
> '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/importlib/**pycache**/_abc.cpython-310.pyc'
> import 'importlib._abc' # <_frozen_importlib_external.SourceFileLoader
> object at 0x104427520>
> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/**pycache**/contextlib.cpython-310.pyc
> matches
> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/contextlib.py
> code object from
> '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/**pycache**/contextlib.cpython-310.pyc'
> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/collections/**pycache**/**init**.cpython-310.pyc
> matches
> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/collections/**init**.py
> code object from
> '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/collections/**pycache**/**init**.cpython-310.pyc'
> import 'itertools' # <class '_frozen_importlib.BuiltinImporter'>
> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/**pycache**/keyword.cpython-310.pyc
> matches
> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/keyword.py
> code object from
> '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/**pycache**/keyword.cpython-310.pyc'
> import 'keyword' # <_frozen_importlib_external.SourceFileLoader object
> at 0x104472d40>
> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/**pycache**/operator.cpython-310.pyc
> matches
> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/operator.py
> code object from
> '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/**pycache**/operator.cpython-310.pyc'
> import '_operator' # <class '_frozen_importlib.BuiltinImporter'>
> import 'operator' # <_frozen_importlib_external.SourceFileLoader
> object at 0x104472e00>
> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/**pycache**/reprlib.cpython-310.pyc
> matches
> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/reprlib.py
> code object from
> '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/**pycache**/reprlib.cpython-310.pyc'
> import 'reprlib' # <_frozen_importlib_external.SourceFileLoader object
> at 0x104473010> import '_collections' # <class
> '_frozen_importlib.BuiltinImporter'> import 'collections' #
> <_frozen_importlib_external.SourceFileLoader object at 0x104470970>
> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/**pycache**/functools.cpython-310.pyc
> matches
> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/functools.py
> code object from
> '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/**pycache**/functools.cpython-310.pyc'
> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/**pycache**/types.cpython-310.pyc
> matches
> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/types.py
> code object from
> '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/**pycache**/types.cpython-310.pyc'
> import 'types' # <_frozen_importlib_external.SourceFileLoader object
> at 0x1044a49a0> import '_functools' # <class
> '_frozen_importlib.BuiltinImporter'> import 'functools' #
> <_frozen_importlib_external.SourceFileLoader object at 0x104473af0>
> import 'contextlib' # <_frozen_importlib_external.SourceFileLoader
> object at 0x104427730> import 'importlib.util' #
> <_frozen_importlib_external.SourceFileLoader object at 0x104426ef0>
> import 'runpy' # <_frozen_importlib_external.SourceFileLoader object
> at 0x104426620>  possible namespace for /Users/ernest/tmp/install/venv
> possible namespace for /Users/ernest/tmp/install/venv
> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/venv/**pycache**/**init**.cpython-310.pyc
> matches
> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/venv/**init**.py
> code object from
> '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/venv/**pycache**/**init**.cpython-310.pyc'
> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/logging/**pycache**/**init**.cpython-310.pyc
> matches
> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/logging/**init**.py
> code object from
> '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/logging/**pycache**/**init**.cpython-310.pyc'
> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/**pycache**/re.cpython-310.pyc
> matches
> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/re.py
> code object from
> '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/**pycache**/re.cpython-310.pyc'
> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/**pycache**/enum.cpython-310.pyc
> matches
> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/enum.py
> code object from
> '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/**pycache**/enum.cpython-310.pyc'
> import 'enum' # <_frozen_importlib_external.SourceFileLoader object at
> 0x1044a77f0>
> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/**pycache**/sre_compile.cpython-310.pyc
> matches
> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/sre_compile.py
> code object from
> '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/**pycache**/sre_compile.cpython-310.pyc'
> import '_sre' # <class '_frozen_importlib.BuiltinImporter'>
> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/**pycache**/sre_parse.cpython-310.pyc
> matches
> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/sre_parse.py
> code object from
> '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/**pycache**/sre_parse.cpython-310.pyc'
> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/**pycache**/sre_constants.cpython-310.pyc
> matches
> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/sre_constants.py
> code object from
> '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/**pycache**/sre_constants.cpython-310.pyc'
> import 'sre_constants' # <_frozen_importlib_external.SourceFileLoader
> object at 0x104505ea0> import 'sre_parse' #
> <_frozen_importlib_external.SourceFileLoader object at 0x104505690>
> import 'sre_compile' # <_frozen_importlib_external.SourceFileLoader
> object at 0x104504dc0> import '_locale' # <class
> '_frozen_importlib.BuiltinImporter'>
> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/**pycache**/copyreg.cpython-310.pyc
> matches
> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/copyreg.py
> code object from
> '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/**pycache**/copyreg.cpython-310.pyc'
> import 'copyreg' # <_frozen_importlib_external.SourceFileLoader object
> at 0x104507700> import 're' #
> <_frozen_importlib_external.SourceFileLoader object at 0x1044a6f80>
> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/**pycache**/traceback.cpython-310.pyc
> matches
> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/traceback.py
> code object from
> '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/**pycache**/traceback.cpython-310.pyc'
> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/**pycache**/linecache.cpython-310.pyc
> matches
> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/linecache.py
> code object from
> '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/**pycache**/linecache.cpython-310.pyc'
> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/**pycache**/tokenize.cpython-310.pyc
> matches
> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/tokenize.py
> code object from
> '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/**pycache**/tokenize.cpython-310.pyc'
> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/**pycache**/token.cpython-310.pyc
> matches
> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/token.py
> code object from
> '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/**pycache**/token.cpython-310.pyc'
> import 'token' # <_frozen_importlib_external.SourceFileLoader object
> at 0x104538ee0> import 'tokenize' #
> <_frozen_importlib_external.SourceFileLoader object at 0x104538640>
> import 'linecache' # <_frozen_importlib_external.SourceFileLoader
> object at 0x1045383d0> import 'traceback' #
> <_frozen_importlib_external.SourceFileLoader object at 0x104507940>
> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/**pycache**/weakref.cpython-310.pyc
> matches
> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/weakref.py
> code object from
> '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/**pycache**/weakref.cpython-310.pyc'
> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/**pycache**/_weakrefset.cpython-310.pyc
> matches
> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/_weakrefset.py
> code object from
> '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/**pycache**/_weakrefset.cpython-310.pyc'
> import '_weakrefset' # <_frozen_importlib_external.SourceFileLoader
> object at 0x10453a110> import 'weakref' #
> <_frozen_importlib_external.SourceFileLoader object at 0x1045398a0>
> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/collections/**pycache**/abc.cpython-310.pyc
> matches
> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/collections/abc.py
> code object from
> '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/collections/**pycache**/abc.cpython-310.pyc'
> import 'collections.abc' #
> <_frozen_importlib_external.SourceFileLoader object at 0x10453abc0>
> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/**pycache**/string.cpython-310.pyc
> matches
> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/string.py
> code object from
> '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/**pycache**/string.cpython-310.pyc'
> import '_string' # <class '_frozen_importlib.BuiltinImporter'> import
> 'string' # <_frozen_importlib_external.SourceFileLoader object at
> 0x10453acb0>
> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/**pycache**/threading.cpython-310.pyc
> matches
> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/threading.py
> code object from
> '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/**pycache**/threading.cpython-310.pyc'
> import 'threading' # <_frozen_importlib_external.SourceFileLoader
> object at 0x10453b220> import 'atexit' # <class
> '_frozen_importlib.BuiltinImporter'> import 'logging' #
> <_frozen_importlib_external.SourceFileLoader object at 0x104470bb0>
> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/**pycache**/shutil.cpython-310.pyc
> matches
> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/shutil.py
> code object from
> '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/**pycache**/shutil.cpython-310.pyc'
> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/**pycache**/fnmatch.cpython-310.pyc
> matches
> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/fnmatch.py
> code object from
> '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/**pycache**/fnmatch.cpython-310.pyc'
> import 'fnmatch' # <_frozen_importlib_external.SourceFileLoader object
> at 0x104581cc0> import 'errno' # <class
> '_frozen_importlib.BuiltinImporter'>  extension module 'zlib' loaded
> from
> '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/lib-dynload/zlib.cpython-310-darwin.so'
> extension module 'zlib' executed from
> '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/lib-dynload/zlib.cpython-310-darwin.so'
> import 'zlib' # <_frozen_importlib_external.ExtensionFileLoader object
> at 0x104581ff0>
> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/**pycache**/bz2.cpython-310.pyc
> matches
> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/bz2.py
> code object from
> '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/**pycache**/bz2.cpython-310.pyc'
> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/**pycache**/_compression.cpython-310.pyc
> matches
> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/_compression.py
> code object from
> '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/**pycache**/_compression.cpython-310.pyc'
> import '_compression' # <_frozen_importlib_external.SourceFileLoader
> object at 0x1045828f0>  extension module '_bz2' loaded from
> '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/lib-dynload/_bz2.cpython-310-darwin.so'
> extension module '_bz2' executed from
> '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/lib-dynload/_bz2.cpython-310-darwin.so'
> import '_bz2' # <_frozen_importlib_external.ExtensionFileLoader object
> at 0x104582e00> import 'bz2' #
> <_frozen_importlib_external.SourceFileLoader object at 0x104582110>
> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/**pycache**/lzma.cpython-310.pyc
> matches
> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/lzma.py
> code object from
> '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/**pycache**/lzma.cpython-310.pyc'
> extension module '_lzma' loaded from
> '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/lib-dynload/_lzma.cpython-310-darwin.so'
> extension module '_lzma' executed from
> '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/lib-dynload/_lzma.cpython-310-darwin.so'
> import '_lzma' # <_frozen_importlib_external.ExtensionFileLoader
> object at 0x1045834c0> import 'lzma' #
> <_frozen_importlib_external.SourceFileLoader object at 0x104582e60>
> import 'shutil' # <_frozen_importlib_external.SourceFileLoader object
> at 0x1044a6140>
> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/**pycache**/subprocess.cpython-310.pyc
> matches
> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/subprocess.py
> code object from
> '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/**pycache**/subprocess.cpython-310.pyc'
> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/**pycache**/signal.cpython-310.pyc
> matches
> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/signal.py
> code object from
> '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/**pycache**/signal.cpython-310.pyc'
> import 'signal' # <_frozen_importlib_external.SourceFileLoader object
> at 0x104630790>  extension module 'fcntl' loaded from
> '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/lib-dynload/fcntl.cpython-310-darwin.so'
> extension module 'fcntl' executed from
> '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/lib-dynload/fcntl.cpython-310-darwin.so'
> import 'fcntl' # <_frozen_importlib_external.ExtensionFileLoader
> object at 0x104630be0>  extension module '_posixsubprocess' loaded
> from
> '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/lib-dynload/_posixsubprocess.cpython-310-darwin.so'
> extension module '_posixsubprocess' executed from
> '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/lib-dynload/_posixsubprocess.cpython-310-darwin.so'
> import '_posixsubprocess' #
> <_frozen_importlib_external.ExtensionFileLoader object at 0x104630ca0>
> extension module 'select' loaded from
> '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/lib-dynload/select.cpython-310-darwin.so'
> extension module 'select' executed from
> '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/lib-dynload/select.cpython-310-darwin.so'
> import 'select' # <_frozen_importlib_external.ExtensionFileLoader
> object at 0x1046313f0>
> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/**pycache**/selectors.cpython-310.pyc
> matches
> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/selectors.py
> code object from
> '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/**pycache**/selectors.cpython-310.pyc'
> extension module 'math' loaded from
> '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/lib-dynload/math.cpython-310-darwin.so'
> extension module 'math' executed from
> '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/lib-dynload/math.cpython-310-darwin.so'
> import 'math' # <_frozen_importlib_external.ExtensionFileLoader object
> at 0x104631ed0> import 'selectors' #
> <_frozen_importlib_external.SourceFileLoader object at 0x104631540>
> import 'subprocess' # <_frozen_importlib_external.SourceFileLoader
> object at 0x104583f10>
> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/**pycache**/sysconfig.cpython-310.pyc
> matches
> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/sysconfig.py
> code object from
> '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/**pycache**/sysconfig.cpython-310.pyc'
> import 'sysconfig' # <_frozen_importlib_external.SourceFileLoader
> object at 0x104583b20> import 'venv' #
> <_frozen_importlib_external.SourceFileLoader object at 0x104427df0>
> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/venv/**pycache**/**main**.cpython-310.pyc
> matches
> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/venv/**main**.py
> code object from
> '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/venv/**pycache**/**main**.cpython-310.pyc'
> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/**pycache**/argparse.cpython-310.pyc
> matches
> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/argparse.py
> code object from
> '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/**pycache**/argparse.cpython-310.pyc'
> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/**pycache**/gettext.cpython-310.pyc
> matches
> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/gettext.py
> code object from
> '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/**pycache**/gettext.cpython-310.pyc'
> import 'gettext' # <_frozen_importlib_external.SourceFileLoader object
> at 0x1046707f0> import 'argparse' #
> <_frozen_importlib_external.SourceFileLoader object at 0x104632b00>
> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/**pycache**/locale.cpython-310.pyc
> matches
> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/locale.py
> code object from
> '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/**pycache**/locale.cpython-310.pyc'
> import 'locale' # <_frozen_importlib_external.SourceFileLoader object
> at 0x1046338b0>

Unable to find identify what might have changed on the system or caused this. I tried removing pip cache, but no luck.

Any advise is appreciated!

Comment: What does the command `locale` show ?

Comment: Locale output:

~ locale
LANG="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_CTYPE="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=

Comment: Try `LC_ALL=C python3 -v -m venv venv` to see if helps.

Comment: I've ran it and left it ( probably took 20+ minutes) it completed, but I noticed an error :

# code object from '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/__pycache__/locale.cpython-310.pyc'
import 'locale' # <_frozen_importlib_external.SourceFileLoader object at 0x10bd3be80>

Error: [Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/Users/ernest/tmp/install/venv/bin/activate.fish'
# clear builtins._

Comment: Remove `/Users/ernest/tmp/install/venv` and redo `LC_ALL=C python3 -v -m venv venv`

Comment: This time no error but it took 21minute to create the venv as it was hanging at the same locale step.

Answer (score 0):

workaround:

1. Run `pip install virtualenv`  with system default python3
2. Install different version of python by brew
3. use `virtualenv -p \path\to\python .venv` in your project folder